# What is the difference between using 在做，要做 or just only 做 in this sentences

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence

1. pronun + 在做什么?
2. pronun +明天在做什么？
3. pronun +明天要做什么
4. pronun +明天做什么？
5. pronun + 做什么?

Please, help me to understand the subtle differences between these sentences.
As in cases 4) and 5)

Can I use the 做 straight without other words before it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 你**在做**什么? = What are you **doing**? --> *在 indicates it is in the progressive tense, you can add an indicator to make it a past progressive, for example, 你昨天在做什么? but it doesn't work with the future tense*
- 你明天在做什么？ (ungrammatical) 在 is used to indicate a progressive tense, you can't use it with the future tense
- 你明天**要**做什么？ = What do you **need**/ **want** to do tomorrow
- 你明天做什么？ = What (will) you do tomorrow --> *will is implied by the word 'tomorrow'*
- 你做什么? = what are you doing? --> *在 (present progressive tense) is implied in the context when there's no indication of past or future tense, we presume it is in the present and is ongoing*